# Not able to get all roles of fiware accounts

Tags: openstack, fiware

I am implementing a solution where a Fiware user can see his roles assigned to him.

Currently using https://github.com/ging/fiware-cloud-portal code to enhance this feature. Here I am referencing the inbuild function JSTACK.Keystone.params.access.user.roles. I am getting the role as member, however, there are other roles assigned to the user.

[image: Here is the short code]

The above code is a comment which I want to implement. However, there is no cloud_role parameter available.

Can anyone help in this code as how to get all the roles of Fiware account users?

Comment: The development of this code of fiware cloud portal is discontinued so probably some things could not work with the current versions of Keystone/Keyrock.

Comment: @ÁlvaroAlonso Thanks for response. Hence, where can I find the fiware cloud code. Is there any new version available which is currently working with current versions of Keystone/Keyrock